# Why my csv file doesn't pass the internal CSVHelper test?

Tags: .net-core, csvhelper

i'm trying to use CSVHelper inside my project. I created that files:

- [JobApplicationMap.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/Mappers/JobApplicationMap.cs)
- [JobApplicationModel.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/Models/JobApplicationModel.cs)
- [ICsvParserService.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/Services/ICsvParserService.cs)
- [CsvParserService.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/Services/CsvParserService.cs)
- [JobApplicationCSV.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/JobApplicationCSV.cs)
- [Constants.cs](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/blob/master/latex_curriculum_vitae/Constants.cs)

But after executing the JobApplicationCSV.WriteCSV method i'm getting a CSVHelper Exception:

> System.Exception
> HResult=0x80131500
> Nachricht = Header with name 'Company' was not found. If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null. You can also change the functionality to do something else, like logging the issue.
> Quelle = latex_curriculum_vitae
> Stapelüberwachung:
> at latex_curriculum_vitae.Services.CsvParserService.ReadCsvFileToJobApplicationModel(String path) in C:\Users\Sasch\source\repos\Visual Studio\latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet\latex_curriculum_vitae\Services\CsvParserService.cs:line 51
> at latex_curriculum_vitae.JobApplicationCSV.WriteCSV(String company, String jobtitle, String city, String joburl) in C:\Users\Sasch\source\repos\Visual Studio\latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet\latex_curriculum_vitae\JobApplicationCSV.cs:line 17
> at latex_curriculum_vitae.MainWindow.BtnGenerate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Sasch\source\repos\Visual Studio\latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet\latex_curriculum_vitae\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 106

I pre created a CSV file in path, with the header:

> Company,Jobtitle,City,Status,EmailSent,JobOfferUrl

So i actually don't know why it don't passes the test. Maybe i have missed anything?

Comment: Hi. One hor ago i committed the last changes. I removed the casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of CsvHelper you are using uses `CurrentCulture` to get the delimiter.  It appears your are in Germany, so your delimiter would be ";" instead of ",".  The current version of CsvHelper forces you to pass in a `CultureInfo` object to `CsvReader` and `CsvWriter` with the suggestion of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to try and mediate this issue.

In your `CsvParserService` try adding the following to both the `ReadCsvFileToJobApplicationModel()` and `WriteNewCsvFile()` methods.

```cs
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
```

Comment: Thank you @david-specht. I haven't known, that the delimiter is culture dependend. Thank you very much. It now works as expected :-)